# Riemann integrable vs Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $[a,b]$. Assume $f$ is Riemann integrable with strictly positive Riemann integral over $[a,b]$ then $f$ is strictly positive on some nonempty open interval.

What if Lebesgue integrable instead of Riemann?

*What I'm thinking is the following for Riemann.

Assume otherwise, then for all open interval, say $(a',b')$,$\int_{a'}^{b'}f(x) dx\leq 0$. Since $f$ is Riemann-integrable with strictly positive Riemann integral over $[a,b]$, $\int_a^b f(x)dx< 0$. Let $a'\rightarrow a$, and $b'\rightarrow b
$, then $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that if $|a-a'|<\delta$ and $|b-b'|<\delta$, then $|\int_a^b f(x)dx-\int_{a'}^{b'}f(x)dx|<\epsilon$. By letting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, we'll have $\int_a^bf(x)dx\leq 0$, contradiction.

Is this correct? and what about Lebesgue?

Comment: Why is $\int_{a'}^{b'} f(x)dx \le 0$? This does not follow

Comment: shouldn't it be: assume otherwise, then for every open interval $(a',b')$, $f$ is not strictly positve on that interval? (that doesn't imply that the integral over that interval is negative)

Comment: Typically, for lebesgue integration you should expect things to happen "almost surely".

Comment: @N.S. Was the proof ok for Riemann? Thank you!

Comment: At the end of the second sentence of the proof, should $\int_a^b f(x)dx< 0$ be $\int_a^b f(x)dx > 0$?

Comment: Your first line of proof is wrong. The exact counter statement is that for every open interval $I$ there is a point $x\in I$ such that that $f(x) \leq 0$. You on the other hand think that $f\leq 0$ on whole of $I$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Then how should I prove the statement for Riemann? Thank you!

Comment: An answer here uses Darboux sums. And in comment to that answer I have linked another proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theorem is false in the Lebesgue setting. Consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 1 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases} .$$
Your very first sentence of your "proof" is wrong.

EDIT: I just realized this was meant to be a proof for Riemann-integrable functions, not Lebesgue.

Comment: The OP's proof was for Riemann integrals, and it seems to be fine. Then the OP's other question was whether the same theorem is true for Lebesgue integrals.

Answer (score 10):

The proof for Riemann could be easier.

Since $\int_a^bf(x)dx>0$, there is a Partition $P$ such that $L(P,f)>0$, where $L(P,f)$ means Darboux lower sum. So there must be a interval, where $\inf f>0$

Comment: This is much better than Apostol's proof (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2350319/72031) +1

Answer (score 4):

For Lebesgue integrals, this is not even true up to modification on a set of measure zero. Take for instance the indicator function of a "fat" Cantor set (cf. page 39 of Folland's 'Real Analysis').

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) describes such a set. It's indicator function is a good counter-example.